# Clearing a dynamic range that might be empty

Tags: excel, vba

If I define a dynamic named range `Foo` like `=OFFSET(sheet!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(sheet!$A$2:$A$1048576 ),1)`, I can clear it like so from VBA:

```
Me.Range("Foo").Clear
```

However, that will fail if the range is already clear. I can work around it with

```
On Error Resume Next 'If this reange is clear it errors out.
Me.Range("Foo").Clear
On Error GoTo 0
```

I'd like a cleaner way to see if a named range exists, and is invalid though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you cannot clear Foo is that Foo is in an error state; e.g. it doesn't exist. Your formula defines Foo as having no cells if it has already been cleared and while a named range can exist in an error state, you cannot reference it until it has at least one value even if that value is a zero-length string returned by a formula. In short, the [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) is returning zero so Foo is zero rows high by one column wide.

You could make sure that Foo is at least one row high even if that cell is blank.

```
=OFFSET(sheet!$A$2, 0, 0, MAX(1, COUNTA(sheet!$A$2:$A$1048576 )), 1)
```

If you plan to let Foo occasionally exist in an error state and use `On Error Resume Next` to handle trying to clear nothing then this would be a better formula.

```
=Sheet!$A$2:INDEX(sheet!$A$2:$A$1048576, MATCH("zzz", $A$2:$A$1048576))
```

That assumes that there is text in column A (you used COUNTA, not COUNT). If there are numbers then,

```
=Sheet!$A$2:INDEX(sheet!$A$2:$A$1048576, MATCH(1e99, $A$2:$A$1048576))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) like thus:

```
Sub test()
  If TypeName(Evaluate("Foo")) = "Range" Then Evaluate("Foo").Clear
End Sub
```

If you run it twice in a row with your sample dynamic range, the first time it clears the data and the second time it gracefully does nothing.

Comment: I like that. I prefer altering my range to always including one row in the case, but that's good to know too..